# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'local')

Tags: angular, google-chrome, google-api

When trying to use the function `chrome.storage.local.set` I get error in console:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'local')
```

How it is possible to solve it?

What didn't work:

1. Adding `/// <reference types="chrome"/>` to my ts file.
2. `npm install --save @types/chrome`
3. Editing manifest.json:

> ```
> {
>  "permissions": [
>     "tabs",
>     "bookmarks",
>     "storage",
>     "unlimitedStorage"
>   ],
>   "optional_permissions": [
>     "unlimitedStorage"
>   ]
> }
> ```

Comment: did ensure that you are running your code in the context of a Chrome extension, either by running it as a content script or by running it in the background page of your extension?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by running as a 'content script'? can you explain?

Comment: Content scripts are files that run in the context of web pages - [source](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/)